# with vsto and excel more and more trying to incorporate visual studio and C#, is VBA dead?

Tags: excel, vba

what is the future for excel vba?  it seems like excel is on its third or fourth version of trying to get VSTO as the mainstream solution here.  Is there a clear strategy?  is vba going to die anytime soon?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can tell you that it's still supported in Office 2010. The VBA library itself actually got an for the first time since VB6. Office 2010 has [introduced support for 64 bit features](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee691831%28office.14%29.aspx#odc_office2010_Compatibility32bit64bit_IntroducingVBA7CodeBase) and a few other small things.

One item of potential concern is that some advanced VBA applications make use of 32 bit ActiveX Controls that may not ever have 64 bit versions released. But for most day to day business applications you should be fairly OK.

Office is very important to Microsoft, so they aren't going to do anything to hurt their business on purpose. I would imagine that whatever they do there will be a roadmap to help people transition to the "new" way.

As for how long it will be until such transitions take place, consider that many business major businesses are still using XP/Office 2003. And we know VBA is supported in Office 2010. If that pattern holds for Office 2010, then in 2017 there will still be major companies on Windows7/Office 2010.

So all in all I wouldn't loose too much sleep over it. Just make sure you hook into Microsoft's developer programs so you can keep an eye on it, and make sure your skills don't go stale.

Comment: +1. Microsoft have a clear goal - eliminate VBA - but IMHO they don't have any working strategy that will bring it about. Office is worth billions of dollars in profit every year and major customers have invested heavily in VBA.

Answer (score 2):

The simple answer is "no, its not going away anytime soon." Microsoft has been clear on this point. There are multiple citations on this, such as:

[Clarification on VBA Support](http://blogs.msdn.com/excel/archive/2008/01/16/clarification-on-vba-support.aspx)

This is also a good read: [The future of VBA looks a lot like VSTA. Or does it?](http://blogs.officezealot.com/hansen/archive/2007/04/12/20245.aspx)

Comment: There is visibly zero new investment in VBA - the IDE hasn't changed in years - but Microsoft simply can't stop supporting VBA, that would be a guaranteed riot, especially among Excel users.

Comment: yeah, you're absolutely right. it was pretty bad when VBA was removed from Mac Office 2008, which has a) a much smaller footprint and b) fanatically religious users who would just as soon not see MSFT on their platform at all. removing it from Office would be one of the worst moves MSFT could make, and I think they know it. but there should really be more investment in the language and VBE - the gap between that and 'fatter' and far more complex technologies like VSTO and OpenXML SDK is just too wide for most power users to even think about moving off of VBA.

Comment: There is some slight change to the VBE in Office 2010. It's mostly cosmetic not functional. But there are a few tiny things like icons etc. (ex: The Add-Ins manager now has a gear icon.) Nothing earth shattering, but it shows that people are still in the code base.

Comment: Yeah, in the new Office 2010 training (I believe on Channel 9) it was saying that VBA developers are actually growing, not decreasing. The barrier to entry is far lower than VSTO/.NET/OOXML. I guess the sheer number of Excel and Access VBA books on a standard B&N or Borders shelf supports that story pretty well.